# How do I modify the contents of a list I pass as a variable length argument?

Tags: python, performance, syntax

I think that the variable length argument turns into a tuple when it enters the edit_list function, so I changed it from a Tuple to a List to edit it. When it returns, I assume it is still treated as a Tuple and therefore no changes to the argument values can be returned?

If so, how would I go about editing the contents of a list that is used in a variable length argument context?

```
def main():
    x = ['hi','hello','world',1,2]
    edit_list(*x)
    print(x)

#why can't I change the list index 1 value to '2' and then
#return the modified arg list to main and then print it out?

def edit_list(*args):
    args = list(args)
    print(args)
    args[1] = 2
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

Comment: You return a list from `edit_list` but you ignore its return value.

Comment: When you are passing via `*x`, you are basically unpacking the list and sending it's values, rather than the list object itself.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to pass in the list directly, instead of unpacking the list using `edit_list(*x)`.

```py
def edit_list(my_list):
   my_list[1] = 2

def main():
   x = [ ... ]
   edit_list(x)
   print(x)
```

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to edit the values that are passed into a variable length argument?

Comment: You can edit the objects themselves, but not change the original container. In essence, `edit_list` in your original implementation has no idea that the elements in `*args` were once part of another list (`x`)

Answer (score 0):

To understand the mechanism of this, you should try to be familiar with the concept "mutable" and "immutable". (of course, only if you want to be better at Python).

Take your code as an example, if the element you passed in is a list, and you are changing the element of that list, you will get a different result.

```
def main():
    x = ['hi',['hello'],'world',1,2]
    edit_list(*x)
    print(x)

# After you run edit_list, the original x will be changed

def edit_list(*args):
    args = list(args)
    print(args)
    args[1][0] = 2
    return args
```

In python, objects are either "mutable" or "immutable". lists for example, are mutable. integers, strings are immutable. When you pass a mutable object to a function, you pass in it's reference so when you edit it(not assigning another object to the variable) you will edit the original object. However, if it's immutable, when you pass in the object to the function, it will generate a copy.

Also use your code as an example. You are effectively doing

```
edit_list("hi", "hello", "world", 1, 2)
```

All the arguments are immutable, so you copied each of them and give them to the function. Therefore, when you are inside the function, you already have different objects to the original. There's nothing you can do to change the original list.

However, if you pass them in as a list

```
edit_list(x)
```

Because `x` is a mutable object, you pass the reference, or the original object in the function. So when you edit the list `lst[1] = 2`, the original one will change. However, if you do something like `lst = [1, 2, 3]`, the original `x` won't be changed, because you just created another object and assigned to the unrelated variable `lst`.